# One server, two DNS records in different networks... How to define which to use

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I have a Hyper-V VM that has 2 virtual NICs, in different networks.

These different networks travel over different physical infrastructure.

Network A is used for management, and goes through a 100Mbps interface. Network B should be used for data, and goes through a 4Gbps interface.

On my domain controller (which is also a DNS server, running Server 2012), the server in question has 2 DNS records... same hostname, 2 different IP's.

When I try to connect to, say, a database on this server, and specify the hostname in my connection string, traffic always goes over the 100Mbps interface.

Is there a way to force the client computer to resolve the IP address of the server in my data network? Do I have to specify the IP address of the server in my connection string?

Comment: Why do you use the same hostname? SImply use two different hostnames.

Comment: The server automatically registers itself on the DNS server, with it's own hostname. However, changing the hostname of the second entry seems like the only option. I thought there may have been some sort of priority of DNS entries, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: There is priority with the SRV records. Not all protocols use them (for instance, HTTP does not, one of its biggest failures.)

Answer (score 1):

On the server in question, configure the NIC connected to Network A to not register in DNS. Then delete the DNS record for the Network A NIC. When you connect by name you'll connect to the name registered by the Network B NIC. When you need to connect to the "management" NIC you can do that by ip address.

Comment: I want to connect to both using the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Manually create an `A` record using a different hostname or just connect directly to the IP address.